# how to Insert Beacon Name to the Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I need to extract BLE device name and put in a table in sqlite. I have used google sample code and modified it to get my aim. all parts work exept puting BLE device name in the table. I can Toast the device name which means the method works, but I dont know where should I put the Insert command: to insert device name to the table.

```
myDb.insertData("1",device.getName(),date);
```

this is my scan activity

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;


public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    //String beaconName;
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss").format(new Date());


    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 50000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        myDb=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        myDb.insertData("1", getName() , date);

        if    (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }



        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported,              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        currently enabled,
        permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new  Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }


        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }





    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS,  device.getAddress());



        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }


    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());


            return view;
        }

    }


    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[]   scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }
}
```

this is the DATAHELPER

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;



public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="mydb.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
    public static final String COL_1="MobileID";
    public static final String COL_2="DeviceName";
    public static final String COL_3="Time";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(MobileID TEXT, DeviceName TEXT,  Time TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String mobileid, String devicename, String time)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,mobileid);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,devicename);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,time);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @ebi-nadian, I have a few questions about your question. Is the name that's being inserting into the database the name of a device that is being connected to through Bluetooth, or is it the local device? Can the application connect to multiple other devices? What is the table "myTable" supposed to keep track of? It would help us understand your question better if answers can be provided to these questions above. Especially the last one.

Comment: Hi Eric, first mytable is inside app database, where all data should be there. the app suppose to scan all BLE devises (Beacons) via GATT packets. there is a lot of information inside the GATT packet like device(Beacon)name, MAC address ..., I only need to get device name(BeaconName) + time + a constant value(For example Number 5) and pass to the sqlite. but my problem is the variable device.getName(); do not propagate to all method (It is only acessable in own method, despite not been private).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the insert command be placed inside the `mLeScanCallback` like so?:

```
...

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[]   scanRecord) {

                // insert the device into the SQLite database
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss").format(new Date());
                myDb.insertData(device.getAddress(), device.getName() , date);

                // add device to list displayed on GUI
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

...
```

The code above uses the mac address of the `BluetoothDevice device` passed into the callback as the `MobileId` for the insert command.

Comment: It works,Thanks, Regarding the Primary key, based on the scenario, the MobileID column MUST be the same for every records in particular mobile phone, the only variable data are Beacon Name and Time, because there are several mobile phones involved to collect data in different areas and finally all data should be merge into one data base .

Comment: Oh, I see, OK. I will edit my answer to fix it then. I'm glad I could help!!